# Is it possible to add list to print statement in Python?

Tags: python

I am working on an assignment and have the assignment completed, but wanted to see if there was a way to utilize the months list under enter_rainfall. When I enter ask user for rain amount I want to know if it possible to add the months_list at the end with index and have the index add one for every iteration. code is below:

```
def main():
    months_list = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
    rain = enter_rainfall()
    average = avg_rainfall(rain)
    low_high = low_High(rain, months_list)

def enter_rainfall():
    rain_fall = []
    months = 12

    for month in range(months):
        rain_amount = float(input('Please enter the amount of rainfall for each month:'))
        rain_fall.append(rain_amount)
    return(rain_fall)

def avg_rainfall(rain):
    total = 0

    for value in rain:
        total += value
    average = total / len(rain)

    print('The total rainfall for the year is', total, 'inches')
    print('The average monthly rainfall is', format(average, '.2f'), 'inches')

    return(average)

def low_High(rain, months_list):
    low_val = min(rain)
    low_month = months_list[rain.index(low_val)]
    high_val = max(rain)
    high_month = months_list[rain.index(high_val)]
    print('The month with the highest rainfall is', high_month)
    print('The month with the lowest rainfall is', low_month)

main()
```

Comment: (1) The month list should be defined as global variable to be accessible outside of `main`

Comment: (2) You can then use the month number ( from 0 to 11) as index into the month list to retrieve the month name.

Comment: @Michael Butscher I am trying to use months_list, but am not sure how to bring it over. Can I add it to the print statement where I define enter_rainfall?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean. The approach of Chris' answer should help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to pass the months into the input function. Don't use globals.

```
def main():
    months_list = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
    rain = enter_rainfall(months_list)
    average = avg_rainfall(rain)
    low_high = low_High(rain, months_list)

def enter_rainfall(months):
    rain_fall = []

    for month in months:
        rain_amount = float(input('Please enter the amount of rainfall for {month}:'.format(month=month)))
        rain_fall.append(rain_amount)
    return(rain_fall)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion this was very helpful.